# Preloaded svg is being loaded again by Angular

Tags: html, angular, svg, preload

I'm just trying to preload a svg sprite in my angular application (index.html):

```
<link rel="preload" href="assets/img/logos/app_white_full.svg" as="image">
<link rel="preload" href="assets/icons/font/symbol-defs.svg" as="image" crossorigin>
```

The file "app_white_full.svg" is being loading once, great!
But the other one, "symbol-defs.svb" which is a svg sprite, is being loaded again by Angular (lines 3 and 8):

[image]

The only difference between those calls that I could see is the Request Headers.

"symbol-defs.svg" from index.html has:

```
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
```

And "symbol-defs.svg" from an Angular component has:

```
Sec-Fetch-Mode: same-origin
```

I don't if it's the issue. Why the other file is ok?

Additionally, I got this message on the console log:

> The resource http://localhost:8080/assets/icons/font/symbol-defs.svg was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

Why is it not recognized as the same?

Comment: An observation: I forgot to remove the "crossorigin" in the link tag. I tryed this but it just adds another Request Header and don't resolve the problem. Please ignore this.